# Unable to Push to GitHub via GitHub for Mac app

Tags: github-for-mac

I created a new Xcode project with GitHub activated. Now I'm ready to share it and push it to my GitHub account. Using GitHub for Mac, I see that the title bar (top-right) contains a "Push to GitHub" button, which I have clicked, filled the sheet that shows up and clicked "Push". All I see is a "Pushing to GitHub) progress indicator, working forever.

I see the following in Console:

> 4/21/12 9:27:59.716 PM GitHub: __43-[GHSSHKeyManager
>   ensurePublicKeysAreSetup]_block_invoke_0 [Line 49] SSH succeeded so
>   the keys must be ok. 4/21/12 9:28:39.353 PM GitHub:
>   __39-[GHPushRepositorySheetController push]_block_invoke_0248 [Line 173] Error Domain=GHGitHubClientErrorDomain Code=667 "Validation
>   Failed" UserInfo=0x104ba4d60 {NSUnderlyingError=0x104811610 "Expected
>   status code in (200-299), got 422",
>   GHGitHubClientErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=422,
>   GHGitHubClientErrorRequestURLKey=https://api.github.com/user/repos,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Validation Failed}

I have performed a validation via Terminal:

> AirMonkey:.ssh tito$ ssh -T git@github.com

I get:

> Hi tciuro! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
>   provide shell access.

Looks like I'm authenticated properly, but I cannot push a brand-new project. Any ideas?

Thanks!

-- Tito